# What is the difference between these 2 function syntax types

Tags: javascript

As the title says, whats the difference between

```
MyFunction = function() {

}
```

and

```
function MyFunction() {

}
```

Nothing?

**Duplicate:** [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: If you close saying duplicate, can you please comment with a link to what it's a duplicate of?

Comment: I prefer adding them to the question - they're easier to find, I think

Comment: @RoBorg fair enough. When I looked it wasn't anywhere was all :)

Comment: dang, sorry about that. didnt spot the dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first form is actually a variable with an **anonymous function** assigned to it, the second is a **declared function**.

They're *almost* interchangeable, but have some differences: debuggers have a harder time with anons (because they lack a name) and the JS engine can directly access declared functions wherever they exist in the script, but anons can't be accessed until they have been assigned.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean

```
var MyFunction = function() {
}
```

And in many cases, there is little difference.

The var syntax is sometimes useful when you are inside some sort of wrapping class and want to be sure of your namespace (like in greasemonkey).

Also, I believe the function-are-constructors stuff (with .prototype, etc) do not work with the var syntax.

Answer (score 0):

here is one difference:

```
function Moose() {
   alert(arguments.callee.name); // "Moose"
}
var Cow = function() {
   alert(arguments.callee.name); // ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*`function myFunction(){}`* is the same as *`var myFunction = function myFunction(){}`*. If you just do *`MyFunction = function(){}`*, it's like *`MyFunction = function anonymous(){}`*.

The variables and functions have different scopes but the function can only be referenced outside the function via the variable name, which needs to be bound to the function.

*`function myFunction(){}`* binds the `myFunction` variable to a function that just happens to have the same name.

Comment: You'd think so, but there's a very subtle difference.  As a very simple example (due to character limit)
var foo = function(){alert(foo)}; f = foo; foo = 5; f() // alerts '5'
var foo = function foo(){alert(foo);} f = foo; foo = 5; f() // alerts with our function

Comment: And I would be right for your case: a function's own name is in its own scope, whereas the outer "foo" is in an outer scope.

Answer (score -1):

There's one subtle difference on Firefox, when you're declaring a window `load` event handler. Declaring the following in a script tag only works on Firefox:

```
function onload() {
    alert(42);
}
```

You have to do it like this for IE, Opera, Safari or Chrome:

```
onload = function () {
    alert(42);
}
```

Comment: isn't this a different issue? onload isn't a local -- its a member of window. your code is really saying "window.onload = function() { blah }, which is a different idea

Comment: the first will work because there's effectively an implicit with(window) so it actually assigns to window.onload, and would be just as broken as the second form if it was declared "var onload..." - this is an absolutely horrible implementation of onload event binding though

Comment: @Jimmy: Whether it's a different "issue" at the core or not, this is answering the question of whether there's "absolutely no difference at all" between the two declaration types. It seems that there is one odd scenario that there is.

Comment: @annakata: I agree that the first form is absolutely horrible. I'm just trying to illustrate a difference in behaviour that I had accidentally discovered while playing around with a unit test framework.

Comment: it's not a difference in behaviour because it's doing something else entirely - this is one of those "there is no spoon" moments